# multiplication equivalent of the summation symbol

Tags: notation

I was curious (even though this is a very amateur question)... what would the multiplication equivalent of sigma (the summation symbol) be?
$$\sum$$
I want to do a series of multiplication of terms.... instead of addition...

Answer (score 42, accepted):

It's a capital pi (for product): $\prod$. You can sometimes find useful symbols and guess what they mean from their [$\LaTeX$ names](http://artofproblemsolving.com/wiki/index.php?title=LaTeX:Symbols), although I guess the most reliable way to find useful, well-known symbols is just to read a lot of math.

Comment: There is also the [table of mathematical symbols](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Table_of_mathematical_symbols) on wikipedia.

Comment: Ah! That's much better than what I said.

Comment: @tekknolagi By the way, to typeset this symbol in LaTeX, one would use the \prod command rather than the greek symbol \Pi (or \pi). This is similar to preferring \sum to \Sigma.

Comment: @QiaochuYuan, What is the name of this operation? (e.g. The name of sigma is summation.)

Answer (score 3):

I google "latex symbols" when I need something I can't recall. That'll give you many lists and tips. For example, if you choose the first hit, the [AoPS list](http://www.artofproblemsolving.com/Wiki/index.php/LaTeX:Symbols) and look for the sum symbol you'll find the product symbol right below it. This is but a simple example of a general technique of exploiting organization and classification on the web to discover information about similar items.

For the inverse, when you know the symbol but not the name there is [deTeXify](http://detexify.kirelabs.org/classify.html) which let's you draw the symbol and does OCR to find the name. For deeper questions there's the [(La)Tex SE site.](https://tex.stackexchange.com/)